# Genomic distribution of tRNAs in eukaryotes

Tags: genomics, gene

The title says it all. I'm doing a literature search trying to see what is widely known and/or well established. I've found a couple of mentions that tRNAs are dispersed throughout the entire nuclear genome. Does this mean they are isolated from each other? Or do they occur in clusters? Is this true across eukaryotes? Or is any of this even well studied?

Comment: The positions are annotated but I don't think anyone did a comparison.  Surprisingly, the gencode GTF does not have the tRNA annotations!! Have a look at [this](http://gtrnadb.ucsc.edu/genomes/eukaryota/Hsapi19/Hsapi19-gene-list.html) database of tRNAs.

Answer (score 1):

In Drosophila, at least, some are clustered (e.g. [these](http://flybase.org/reports/FBgn0011956.html)), but there are many tRNA genes in eukaryotes, so overall they are dispersed. You might find the [Genomic tRNA Database](http://gtrnadb.ucsc.edu) useful, and the [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4702915/pdf/gkv1309.pdf) describing it.